# EntityFramework Insert fails due to Trigger and OptimisticConcurrencyException is thrown, how to handle it?

Tags: entity-framework, triggers, entity-framework-6

I have a trigger in DB that forbids inserting duplicated data. When I enter duplicated data, it adds nothing to the table, OptimisticConcurrencyException is thrown and I am swallowing (ignoring) this exception. When I try to enter new correct object, EF tries to run both INSERTs and it fails again on the first one.

How can I recover from this, all examples are discussing failed UPDATES, is there anything about INSERT? As I have read creating new DatabaseContext will solve the problem, but I cannot do it that way.

Comment: You should dispose the context after SaveChanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new DatabaseContext is always the best choice (since Hibernate).
In your case you need to remove the entity that caused the error from the context.

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Detach(entity);
```

Comment: In EF6 it will look:  

`Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;`

Answer (score 0):

You can ask `ObjectContext` to ignore all the changes after the ignorable exception is thrown. This way the added entity is marked `Unchanged`; hence in the next `SaveChanges` call, context won't consider it to manipulate DB:

```
(yourContextObject as IObjectContextAdapter).AcceptAllChanges();
```